# Automatically map props of a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Imagine a component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    render = () => <div>value: {this.props.x}</div>        
}
```

and a method:

```
const transform = x => x + 1;
```

Is it possible to apply the method `transform` automatically and only once in the component without call it from the parent ?

---

For example if I call it as

```
<MyComponent x={1}/>
```

He displays

```
<div>value: 2</div>
```

But i don't want to write

```
render = () => <div>value: {transform(this.props.x)}</div>
```

because it would mean that i have to call `transform` every time i access to `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a way myself !

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    render = () => <div>value: {this.props.x}</div>        
}

const mapProps = Component => props => <Component x={transform(props.x)}/>

export default mapProps(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Why not just call the method on your props in the constructor of your component? No need for a higher order component for this type of transformation.

Comment: There may be several reasons for that. In my case i have a generic wrapper between the parent and the child waiting of a kind of input. More generally it can allow to simplify the component API.

Comment: But isn't that the same thing as changing the props in the constructor? You're creating a higher order component that transforms the prop before rendering, which is kind of the same thing.

Comment: Ok i thought you mean in the parent. if I'm not mistaken
props are immutables.

Comment: You are correct. My bad, I meant assign a new var in the constructor based on your prop, same way you're creating a new prop `x` with the higher order component.

Comment: It means that you have 2 variables, `this.props.x` and `this.x`. It seems to be less readabe and a source of confusion.